# Automatic Registration Script

Tags: java, scripting, web

I've started programming about a year ago when I started my bacherlor degree in computer science at a University. So I can get around pretty okay in programming by now. However, at the moment I'm looking to create an automatic script which basically registers me for a certain room.

In order to register me for a room, I have to login in at a website (https://www.supersaas.com/), select a time-schedule and confirm my choice.

Now I've figured I can create a windows task which is scheduled at the time the rooms get available, to execute the program. However I have no clue as to where I have to start programming in order to send these HTTP requests to the website in a java-based program. Where do I start?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/ and generate java code with automation register.